# Checking for a specific letter in a BAT file

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I'm simply looking to find the correct syntax for having a BAT file check for a specific letter, an if that letter is not a valid selection, to go to an error.
My first three lines of code work, but the statements checking if the letter entered is NOT a C or an R simply makes the BAT file exit, instead of going to my error.

```
IF /I "%input%"=="C" goto compile
IF /I "%input%"=="R" goto run
IF /I "%input%"=="" goto error
IF /I "%input%"!="C" goto error
IF /I "%input%"!="R" goto error
```

What is the correct Syntax please for the last two lines of code?

Comment: Type `if /?` into a Command Prompt window and read the output help text…

Comment: `choice /?` might be a better choice.

Comment: If you are already checking if the variable is equal to `C` or `R` what is the point of checking if it is NOT `C` or `R`? The third line of your code could just be `GOTO ERROR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As another user suggested, look at `CHOICE` https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html

To answer your direct questions:

you need to use the `NOT` operator

```
IF /I NOT "%input%"=="C" goto error
```

OR

```
IF /I "%input%" NEQ "C" goto error
```

All I think you need to do is simply replace you last 2 lines with your error handling and then `goto end`  That way if you get to this point it's an error.  Add a `goto end` before your `:compile` and `:run` labels to prevent wrongful execution.

```
IF /I "%input%"=="C" goto compile
IF /I "%input%"=="R" goto run
:error
//handle your error...
goto end
:compile
//handle compile
goto end
:run
//handle run
:end
//handle end
```

For reference:

https://ss64.com/nt/if.html